# Why do I get an error message: "non-conformable arguments", even though I have no NA values in my matrix?

Tags: r

I am trying to run the r code from Network-Analysis on Attitudes: A Brief Tutorial.

You can find it [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/suppl/10.1177/1948550617709827).

First we loaded the cognitive attitudes.

```
unzip('ANES2012.zip')
ANES2012 <- read.dta('anes_timeseries_2012_Stata12.dta')#loads the data to the object ANES2012

#########################
#Recode variables 
#Items regarding Obama

ObamaCog <- data.frame(Mor = as.numeric(ANES2012$ctrait_dpcmoral),#this creates a data frame containing the items tapping beliefs
                        Led = as.numeric(ANES2012 $ ctrait_dpclead),
                        Car = as.numeric(ANES2012$ctrait_dpccare),
                        Kno = as.numeric(ANES2012$ctrait_dpcknow),
                        Int = as.numeric(ANES2012$ctrait_dpcint),
                        Hns = as.numeric(ANES2012$ctrait_dpchonst))
ObamaCog[ObamaCog < 3] <- NA#values below 3 represent missing values
```

I had to change the code a little bit, as the `.binarize` function didn't work. (I couldn't load a package ("cmprsk") that was necessary.) So I installed `library(biclust)` and was able to binarize the data:

```
ObamaCog <- binarize(ObamaCog, threshold = 5)
```

Then we did the same for the affective attitudes:

```
ObamaAff <- data.frame(Ang = as.numeric(ANES2012$candaff_angdpc),#this creates a data frame containing the items tapping feelings
                        Hop = as.numeric(ANES2012$candaff_hpdpc), 
                        Afr = as.numeric(ANES2012$candaff_afrdpc), 
                        Prd = as.numeric(ANES2012$candaff_prddpc))
ObamaAff[ObamaAff < 3] <- NA#values below 3 represent missing values
ObamaAff <- binarize(ObamaAff, 4)#(not) endorsing the feelings is encoded as 1 (0)
```

And created one `Obama`-matrix out of it:

```
Obama <- data.frame(ObamaCog,ObamaAff)
```

Then we are omitting the NA values:

```
Obama <- na.omit(Obama)
```

And I checked:

```
write.csv(Obama, file = "Obama-Excel1")
```

There are no more NA values in my matrix.

And I think it fits the required structure: nobs x nvars

```
    Mor Led Car Kno Int Hns Ang Hop Afr Prd
2     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

...

```
60    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
61    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
62    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
63    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
65    0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
66    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
67    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

until 5914. And if there was an NA-value in the row before, it is now missing. (For example row 64)

If I am then trying to run the `IsingFit`-function:

```
ObamaFit <- IsingFit(Obama)
```

It doesn't work, I am getting the error message:

```
Error in y %*% rep(1, nc) : non-conformable arguments
```

I am a beginner in R and I assumed that non-conformable arguments are `NA`-values, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Can anyone tell me, what the error message means and how I might solve the problem, so I can use the `IsingFit`-function?

Comment: The [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/IsingFit/man/isingfit.html) is pretty clear that `IsingFit` expects a matrix as input. You pass a data.frame instead. Does it work if you do `ObamaFit <- IsingFit(as.matrix(Obama))` instead?

Comment: @Roland It still gives me the very same error message. With `ObamaFit <- IsingFit(as.matrix(Obama))`

But thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: Well, does your matrix have the required structure, i.e., "The dimension of the matrix is nobs x nvars; each row is a vector of observations of the variables. Must be cross-sectional data."?

Comment: @Roland I included some information on the data structure in the post now. I don't think that this is the problem. Or do you still think so?